# Looping through set of images and displaying them one by one using DrawImageUnscaled

Tags: c#, image, animation, for-loop

I am developing a Windows Forms application which consist of a single image on the screen and a button called animate when it loads up. When the button is clicked, it is supposed to loop through 10 images (saved in the folder as "1.png", "2.png"…"10.png") and display them one after another, creating an animation effect.

However, when I click the animate button, it doesn't do anything. However, if I click on the screen after clicking the animate button, it displays the last image ("10.png") saved in the directory.

This is the code that I have for the `Form1_Paint()` method: this is applied when the form loads up.

(`pictureBit` is the name of the original image)

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics windowG = e.Graphics;

    if (animate)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Bitmap images = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(i+".png");
            windowG.DrawImageUnscaled(images, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        windowG.DrawImageUnscaled(pictureBit, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, it sets a Boolean to true:

```
private void start_animate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    animate = true;
}
```

What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: where is the button click event.. are you using the debugger .. also where is `animate` declared.. if you post code here on `SO` please post all relevant code..

Comment: You are iterating all your pictures in the paint event. It doesn't get called till you do something to invalidate the image, and it will only show the last one. You need to use a timer.  Setting the image to a variable and invalidating the hosting control in the timers tick event to trigger the paint event to draw the picture .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are looping inside the `Paint` event handler. At best, this will cause the rest of your program to freeze while the image is animated, and at worst (as in your scenario) you will find that due to the way that Windows handles screen updates, the on-screen image is updated only after the handler returns, preventing you from seeing the animation at all.

For simple animation such as what you're doing, the easiest thing to do would be to update the `Bitmap` on a timer and invalidate the form, and have the `Paint` event handler only draw the one time. For example:

```
private Bitmap _currentImage;

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{            
    if (animate)
    {                            
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(_currentImage, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(pictureBit, 0, 0);
    }
```

}

```
private async void start_animate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    animate = true;
    int imageIndex = 1;

    while (animate)
    {
        _currentImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageIndex  + ".png");
        Invalidate();

        await Task.Delay(100); // wait 100 milliseconds

        imageIndex++;
        if (imageIndex > 10)
        {
            imageIndex = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Using `async` and `await` here allows you to have code that looks like a normal loop, but which allows the method to return and for the thread to continue processing in between each invalidation (i.e. when `await Task.Delay(100)` is executed).

Note that the above focuses on trying to animate the image on a fixed interval. There is no guarantee that the form will actually be redrawn as frequently as you update the image. Usually for animation this is still preferable (i.e. you might miss some frames, but the overall animation occurs at the expected rate). But you can coordinate the animation loop and the `Paint` event handler if you want, so that the animation loop only proceeds to the next frame once it's been signaled that the event handler has updated the form.

Also note that the "fixed interval" above does not take into account any of the overhead dealing with the file I/O and index. A more precise timing could be accomplished by using `Stopwatch` to keep track of how long that overhead takes and subtracting that from the delay in the loop. Since your original code made no attempt whatsoever to schedule the animation on a particular timing interval, I figured the above code example doesn't need any more precision than what it has now. :)

Warning: since you have not provided [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not practical to create a whole program from scratch to verify a proposed solution. The above is just browser code; I've already edited it once to fix syntax and logic issues I found reviewing it, but I can't guarantee that there aren't more. :) I assume that the basic idea is sufficiently presented for you to adapt to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's not going to work the way you think.  The results of Paint aren't forwarded to the device (screen) until some time after the method returns; this allows the windowing system to do some optimizations.  So your Paint method basically draws *all ten images* before anything is sent to the screen.

The reason you don't see *anything* until you click the form is because Paint is only called when the Form thinks it needs to be redrawn.  Simply changing a Control's content may not cause that to happen.  Take a look at the [Control::Invalidate()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjW5rWExvzIAhXK6CYKHTXEDEg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F598t492a(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHmzwNjJr34YpFYdgRIWA7bDEzDxQ&sig2=voHWt12iW_OXRK7AYqFE-A&bvm=bv.106923889,d.eWE) method.

What you might consider is using a [System::Windows::Forms::Timer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjol73vxfzIAhWCRyYKHcalAaE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.timer(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNExmJnHGdGUlTDUW3Y_i7TSoF7dNQ&sig2=gWHFa2ALsE6uNaDqEY7p7g&bvm=bv.106923889,d.eWE) to periodically update the image and invalidate the control (if needed).  This keeps it all on the Forms thread and also allows you to have some control over the rate at which the images change.  Your button click could start the timer.

I also suggest loading all the images into memory ahead of time instead of reading each one from file at the moment you intend to display it.